# SharePoint online SCA for all sites in the tenant

Tags: sharepoint-online, online

Is it possible to be a SCA for all sites in a tenant? Right now we are running into an issue of our SCA's having to be added to each individual site collection. We have the user accounts assigned to a role of SharePoint admin, do they need to be a global admin?

Answer (score 1):

Unlike SharePoint on-prem, it is not possible to automatically apply at a higher level full control to all sites (i.e. a Web Application policy). With SharePoint Online, you will need to assign SCA on an individual site basis.

That can be automated, for example via a [Site Design](https://docs.microsoft.com/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/get-started-create-site-design) that calls a [Flow](https://docs.microsoft.com/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/site-design-trigger-flow-tutorial) which calls [Azure Automate](https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/automation/automation-quickstart-create-runbook) which runs the cmdlet `Set-SPOUser -site $url -LoginName jdoe@contoso.onmicrosoft.com -IsSiteCollectionAdmin $true`. You can change the [default site design](https://docs.microsoft.com/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/customize-default-site-design) to automatically do this.